# Is there any visual css editor for javafx?

Tags: css, editor, javafx

I recently watched this video - [JavaFX for Business Application Developers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q494jJC7Vpc)  , and the speaker says there is a visual css editor for javafx. But I couldn't find one. Please tell me if you know about such a tool.
Thank you.

Comment: This is NOT off-topic. I found the answer quite useful... who decides these things??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SceneBuilder 1.1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html) has a visual CSS analyzer tool.

Here are some instructions on [using the css analyzer in SceneBuilder](https://blogs.oracle.com/jeromec/entry/using_the_new_css_analyzer).

While SceneBuilder is good for analyzing CSS at design time, in a related way, [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) is useful for analyzing and manipulating style application at run time.

Comment: Link is now dead but answer is still up to date